# Python decorater TypeError in **kwargs

Tags: python, decorator

I am trying to understand python decorator in depth

```
def lol(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print(*args)
        print(**kwargs)
        return func(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper

@lol
def greet(name,lol,l):
    return f'{name}:{lol}:{l}'

greet('tom',"dick",l="harry")
```

so when i give only positional args like `greet('tom',"dick","harry")` this function works but when i give keyword arguments followed by positional argument `greet('tom',"dick",l="harry")` it gives me error.

```
TypeError: 'l' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

but when i re-write my decorator like this

```
def lol(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print(*args)
        print(**kwargs)
        return wrapper(*args,**kwargs)
    return func
```

It works fine. I am little confused what is happening. Would be great if somebody explains it no matter how silly is the cause. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to do:

```
    print(**kwargs)
```

That tries to expand the keyword arguments as keyword arguments to `print`, so in your use case, it's like you typed `print(l="harry")`, which is clearly nonsensical (`print` doesn't take an argument named `l`). Just do:

```
    print(kwargs)
```

to see the `dict` of keyword arguments received. Similarly, `print(args)` is likely to be a better solution than `print(*args)` as it will print `repr`s, which typically tell you more about the arguments for debugging purposes.

The reason your second approach "works fine" is that it doesn't decorate anything. You make `wrapper`, throw it away, then return the original `func`, so the original `func` is called, and `print(**kwargs)` never occurs.

Comment: oppps. such a silly mistake.. thanks for explaining.